# Cocoa - iOS -Does updating the text property of a UILabel require setNeedsDisplay?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uilabel, setneedsdisplay, setneedsdisplayinrect

I am a newbie and I have a iOS project where I am setting the text property of a UILabel field.

```
self.nameLabel.text = @"abcd";
```

**Question**

- Do I need to invoke setNeedsDisplayInRect for the label for the new text value to be displayed ?

**My understanding based on some testing:**

- Without invoking setNeedsDisplayInRect, the the label's text was updated,
- but I want to know if it was a coincidence or is gauranteed that the the label will display the new value without explicitly invoking setNeedsDisplay

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UILabel` will do everything needed for updates when you set its `text` property. Same for its other properties (`font`, `textColor`, etc.) About the only thing you have to do manually (if you're not using IB) is set the `frame`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answer, I have one doubt regarding what you said. Just to clarify if you set the frame in code, then you would need to invoke setNeedsDisplay ?

Comment: No. UIKit takes care of that. I only mentioned `frame` because a lot of people add `UILabel`s without setting the frame (`bounds` actually) and then wonder why it doesn't show up. Often/usually the right thing to do is `[label sizeToFit]`.

Answer (score 0):

If the label does not refresh despite the text update, your CPU may be fully utilized and the following command will force the refresh:

```
self.nameLabel.text = @"abcd";
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
```